# my nodejs bcrypt compare not working properly

Tags: node.js, graphql, bcrypt

am building an app with nodes qraphQl using apollo, am trying to do a login page, but ater signing up and and i try to sign in, my bcrypt would always return false,

in my user model

```
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

const user = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {    
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      unique: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      field: 'id'
    },
    fullname: DataTypes.STRING,
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      },
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowedNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
        isEmail: true, 
      }
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowedNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
        len: [7, 42],
      },
    },
    role: { 
      type: DataTypes.ENUM,
      values: ['ADMIN', 'INSTRUCTOR', 'STUDENT'],
      defaultValue: 'STUDENT'
    }
  });

  User.beforeCreate(async user => {
    user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash()
  });
  User.beforeSave(async user => {
    user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash()
  });

  User.prototype.generatePasswordHash = async function() {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    return await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds)
  };

  User.prototype.validatePassword = async function(password) {
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
  };

  User.associate = models => {
    User.hasMany(models.Message, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
  };

  User.findByLogin = async login => {
    let user = await User.findOne({
      where: { username: login },
    });

    if (!user) {
      user = await User.findOne({
        where: { email: login },
      });
    }

    return user;
  };

  return User;
};

export default user;
```

And in my users resolver, here is the code

```
import { combineResolvers } from 'graphql-resolvers';
import Joi from 'joi'
import { isAuthenticated, isAdmin } from './authorization';
import {SignUp, SignIn} from '../functions/joi'
import {createToken} from '../functions/jwt'

export default {

  Mutation: {
    signUp: async (parent, { username, fullname, email, password, Rpassword}, { models, secret }) => {
      if(password !== Rpassword){
        return new Error('Password did not match')
      }
      var thejoi = { username, fullname, email, password }
      const checkUserEm = await models.User.find({ where: { email: email }})
      if (checkUserEm) {
          return new Error('Email address already Exist')
      }
      const checkUserUs = await models.User.find({ where: { username: username }})
      if (checkUserUs) {
          return new Error('Username already Exist')
      }

      await Joi.validate(thejoi, SignUp, {abortEarly:false})
      const user = await models.User.create({
        username, 
        fullname, 
        email,
        password,
        role:'STUDENT'
      });
      return { token: createToken(user) };
    },
    signIn: async (parent, { login, password }, { models, secret }, ) => {
      var varrh = { password }
      await Joi.validate(varrh, SignIn, {abortEarly:false})
      const user = await models.User.findByLogin(login);

      if (!user) {
        return new Error('No user found with this login credentials.');
      }

      const isValid = await user.validatePassword(password);
      if (!isValid) { 
        return new Error('Invalid password .');
      }

      return { token: createToken(user) };
    }
  },
  User: {
    messages: async (user, args, { models }) => {
      return await models.Message.findAll({
        where: {
          userId: user.id
        }
      });
    },
  },
}
```

pls am really confused because its it suppose to work, i have searched google but it didnt help me, pls how can i solve this issue thanks

Answer (score 1):

inside `generatePasswordHash` you referencing to `this`, but you also using arrow functions for `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave` hooks.

Two options:

1. Do not use arrow function for `beforeCreate` and `beforeSave` hooks.

```
User.beforeCreate(async function (user) {
  user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash()
});

User.beforeSave(async function (user) {
  user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash()
});
```

2. Provide `user` object to `generatePasswordHash` and replace `this` with `user`.

```
User.beforeCreate(async user => {
  user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash(user)
});

User.beforeSave(async user => {
  user.password = await user.generatePasswordHash(user)
});

User.prototype.generatePasswordHash = async function(user) {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    return await bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds)
};
```

Comment: pls how can i do the option 2

Comment: should i use this User.prototype.generatePasswordHash = async function() {
    const saltRounds = 10;
    return await bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds)
  };

Comment: i did console.log(this.password) in the validatePassword and i got the same password as the password in the database but its still returning false

Comment: A database should contain a hashed password instead of a real one.

Comment: it contained thee hashed password

Comment: Okay, what about password variable? Does it contain real password string?